# is it possible to set different heights of cells in Sizeclasses for differnt devices?

Tags: ios, user-interface, storyboard, size-classes

i want to set different heights in my TableView.
On iPad i want 100 and on iPhone 70.

In addition, on iPhone i want to move/delete some UIElements.

My question is: is it possible to do that when using sizeclasses just in storyboards? No code adaption if possible.

So on iPhone i want also to set a different font size. In short words, i want to use ONE Storyboard file with SizeClass and in THIS ONE Storyboard file, i want to set all constraints.

When i am changing the height of a cell for iPhone in storyboard, iPad changes, too.

Whats your recommendation? Is it possible ONLY with SizeClasses? Or should i create a seperate Storyboard for iPhone?

Comment: In xcode 6 you should use only ONE storyboard! You should all this implement in your code (in .m file)

Comment: That means, also autolayouting should i do in code, right? @СергейОлейнич thats heavy work to do autolayout programmatically. is that really the right way?

Comment: If you want to make animation you should write autolayout (NSConstraits). But if you want only present your view you could do this in storyboard. Height for row you should implement in code if you want to do it different.